# asp.net with mysql Unknown column in where clause

Tags: mysql, asp.net

```
enter code here  string customerName = Request.Form[txtSearch.UniqueID];
    string customerId = Request.Form[hfCustomerId.UniqueID];
    Label1.Enabled = true;
    Label1.Text = customerName;
    DataRow dr = GetData("SELECT * FROM actor where first_name = " +txtSearch.Text.ToString() ).Rows[0]; 
    Document document = new Document(PageSize.A4, 88f, 88f, 10f, 10f);
    Font NormalFont = FontFactory.GetFont("Arial", 12, Font.NORMAL, Color.BLACK);
```

Is there any problem with mysql syntax? 
Correct me if i am going wrong. 
While i am searching with a specified value, this runs perfectly. But creating problem when trying to pass a value.

Comment: shouldn't txtSearch.Text be surrounded in brackets?

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
DataRow dr = GetData("SELECT * FROM actor where first_name = '" +txtSearch.Text+"' ).Rows[0];
```

Comment: You are open to SQL Injection. Rather use parameterized query.

Comment: Surely , I have just answered your question . I recommend the use of stored procedures .. because with queries page you are open for SQL Injection.